# Working with files - replacing one line

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I'm trying to overwrite the lines of a file and take out the word "hello". For some reason this isn't working. This is the file:

**out.txt**:

> hello
>   1
>   2
>   goodbye

Here are the errors:

> error: no matching function for call to `'std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char, std::char_traits<char>, int>::istream_iterator(std::fstream)'|`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::fstream("out.txt")),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::fstream("out.txt")),
        [] (std::string str) { return str != "hello"; }
    );
}
```

Comment: Overwriting the file while you are still trying to read it is probably a bad idea. Also you pass in a `std::istream_iterator<>` as third parameter when you actually would need some *output* iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at available constructors for `std::istream_iterator`:

```
istream_iterator();
constexpr istream_iterator();
istream_iterator( istream_type& stream );
istream_iterator( const istream_iterator& other ) = default;
```

You're trying to call third constructor, but you pass a *rvalue*, while a *lvalie* is expected.

Comment: So how do I get this to work? Can you give me the new program?

Comment: @MemyselfandI, 1) Do not pass temporary `fstream` object, just declare it before calling function, 2) Create two objects(`ifstream` and `ofstream`, not for same file), and replace third argument to the `std::ostream_iterator`. Also, you could pass a separator as second argument, say, like this: `std::ostream_iterator(fout, "\n")`.

Comment: Okay it works when I use two different files (for input and output) but how can I get it to replace the lines in the *same* file?

Comment: Couldn't you just move/rename file after writing?

Comment: You could use [`std::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) function.